# Is filming 25 micrometer from opposite sides possible QM event?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

I have a Gaussian process where the mean is 0.381 and the standard deviation is 0.524. 
The process is simplifically the difference of diameters $d_1$ and $d_2$ where $d_1$ is taken from one side, while $d_2$ from the other by CadCam. 
The size of the diameter is about 0.25 - 0.50 micrometers so a QM event could be possible. 
However, I cannot get anything to my mind and my fellows neither, since we think the values should all be 0. 
There may be something QM happening in so small distances. 
A small computational error or setting error would leak do fixed error, but now it is a distribution.

How can filming the disc (etc diameter) both sides be distributed as Gaussian?

Comment: Giving the size of something is not enough to decide if the object's dynamic is due to thermal motion or quantum mechanics (or measurement error...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to invoke QM at all. Measurements are often normally (Gaussian like) distributed due to random errors unavoidable on each individual measurement. Actually, your result 
$d_1-d_2= 0.381 \pm 0.524$ is consistent with the difference being zero (because the error is larger than the obtained average value)